# Weird files in root directory, is secure to delete them?

Tags: files, fedora, filesystems, root-filesystem

What the following files means on the root directory of my Linux (Fedora 25):

```
$ ls -la
total 70
...
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root     0 Nov 22 09:28 1
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     0 Sep 27 09:53 .autorelabel
...
-rw-r--r--    1 root root     0 Dec  9 14:30 null
```

Is secure to delete them? Sometime ago I delete some file (didn't remember the name) and I complete damage the HDD partition and I don't want the same here.

Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a system with SELinux, so you should certainly keep `.autorelabel`. Delete `null` and `1`.

The `.autorelabel` file is used most often when switching from a disabled (permissive) SELinux to an enabled (enforcing) SELinux configuration. It can also be used to correct mistakes made with SELinux when the mistakes were not made a permanent part of the SELinux configuration.

Comment: I can confirm that `null` and `1` were created by known packaging bugs and are safe to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Those are all zero-byte files.  `1` and `null` are almost certainly safe to remove.  If you're really paranoid, you can move them rather than deleting them.